# codeigniter upload encrypt_name uniqueness

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, file-io, overwrite

**1.** Does codeigniter's upload library's `encrypt_name` option check to be unique?

I know that the `overwrite` option is important. If `overwrite` is `TRUE`, it would overwrite and if it's `FALSE`, it would rename the file by adding a number at the end of the name.

The question is: Will it **regenerate** the encrypted name until finding a unique name even if `overwrite` is `TRUE`? I ask this because it's obvious that when we want encrypted name, of course we don't want to overwrite.

The problem with rename by adding some numbers is that it corrupts the size of file names. Many files will have 32 chars filename, and some might have 33 chars filename that corrupts coordination.

**2.** Is that possible to generate an ever-duplicated result at all?

Comment: If `overwrite` is set to `true` then the encoded name if matched with an existing file will replace the earlier file else it will rename the current uploaded file.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, I meant even if overwrite if `FALSE`. Edited the q. Thank you for your note.

Comment: Yes, even it matches a file that is already uploaded which is next to impossible it will rename the file that is being uploaded.

Comment: I was right, but I hadn't given enough information! Updated and explained the challenges in my mind. Thank you `Niloy` for forcing me to explain! `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Codeigniter is using `md5(uniqid(mt_rand()))` to generate the encrypted file name, I'd guess that you'll find your answer in the [PHP docs for uniquid](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

Short answer (for 2.) would be: maybe, but probably not.

And to answer your first question: no, CI doesn't generate a new encrypted filename, if it already exists. It adds a number to the end of the name.

A short glance at the source code of /libraries/Upload.php, line 415, helps.